# Interpreting Mathematica code on black holes

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, physics, astronomy

I am trying to understand the code written down on page 7 of this document (code is in Mathematica) I understand pretty much all of the code on the previous page needed to setup the page 7 code (setting up geodesics etc):

https://www.physics.uci.edu/~etolleru/KerrOrbitProject.pdf

Would appreciate if someone could explain the 2 large code blocks (preferably annotate or somehow show what each part means with respect to the final results/graphs). I get vaguely parts what they are doing but not all of it.

From what I understand,

- 1st block: Sets up code for initial conditions and solutions for the geodesics equations as a list of functions. Not 100% sure on there meaning.
- 2nd block: Putting in actual numerical values for these functions for specific initial conditions and then plotting the curve.

Useful information about the document:

- The code is designed to graph particle orbits around a Kerr black hole. However as a build up to looking at the Kerr black hole the author decides to look at Minkowski and Schwarzschild metric first as they require similiar setup. (code on pg 7 is looking at the Schwarzschild solution).
- The description of what the code on pg7 is doing is at the bottom of pg6. I am just unsure of how it is actually being done.

Comment: Did you contact the author for explanation? Or have you decided not to do that?

Comment: Hey, no I haven't contacted the original author primarily because the paper is over 10years old and didn't quite know how long it would take etc. Thought that If I posted on here someone would be able to figure it out

Comment: This is outdated code. I checked that it does not work on version 11.3. We must write a new one.

Comment: Thanks Alex, how did you know how to edit the old code? Was it from understanding the error messages and then translating the maths over into new code?

Comment: @user61882 Yes, the system localizes errors, and I correct them. It is not difficult, but you need to know the language well and understand what the result should be.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I managed to debug the code from KerrOrbitGRProject and reproduce the results for the Schwarzschild metric (figures on pp. 7-8)

```
coords = {t, r, θ, φ}; n = 
 Length[coords]; a = 0; ρ = 
 r^2 + a^2 Cos[θ]^2; Δ = r^2 \[Minus] 2*M*r + a^2;
tt = 2 M*r/ρ \[Minus] 
  1; rr = ρ/Δ; θθ = ρ; \
φφ = (Δ + (2 M*
       r*(r^2 + 
         a^2))/ρ) Sin[θ]^2; tφ = \[Minus]4 a M \
r Sin[θ]^2/ρ; metric = {{tt, 0, 0, tφ}, {0, rr, 
   0, 0}, {0, 0, θθ, 0}, {tφ, 0, 
   0, φφ}}; metric // MatrixForm
inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]]; inversemetric // MatrixForm
christoffel := 
 christoffel = 
  Simplify[Table[
    1/2*Sum[inversemetric[[i, 
        s]]*(D[metric[[s, j]], coords[[k]]] + 
         D[metric[[s, k]], coords[[j]]] \[Minus] 
         D[metric[[j, k]], coords[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], { i, 1, n}, {j, 
     1, n}, {k, 1, n}]]
 listchristoffel := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[christoffel[[i, j, k]], 
     0 ], {ToString[Γ[i, j, k]], 
     christoffel[[i, j, k]]}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
    j}] TableForm[
   Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listchristoffel], Null], 2 ], 
   TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
geodesic := 
 geodesic = 
  Simplify[Table[\[Minus]Sum[
      christoffel[[i, j, k]] coords[[j]]' coords[[k]]', {j, 1, n}, {k,
        1, n}], {i, 1, n}]]
listgeodesic := 
 Table[{"d/dτ" ToString[coords[[i]]'], " =", geodesic[[i]]}, {i, 
   1, n}]
TableForm[listgeodesic, TableSpacing -> {2}]
maxτ = 750; ivs = {0, 0, .088}; ics = {0, 6.5, π/2, 0}; M = 1;
computeSoln[maxτi_, ivsi_, icsi_] := 
 Block[{ivs, ics, i, χ, tmp, soln}, ics = icsi; 
  ivs = Join[{χ}, ivsi];
  op1 = Table[coords[[i]] -> ics[[i]], {i, 0, n}];
  tm = metric /. op1; 
  tmp = ivs.(tm.ivs); χslv = Solve[tmp == uinvar, χ]; 
  ivs[[1]] = Last[χ /. χslv];

  op = {Derivative[1][t] -> Derivative[1][t][τ], 
    Derivative[1][r] -> Derivative[1][r][τ], 
    Derivative[1][θ] -> Derivative[1][θ][τ], 
    Derivative[1][φ] -> Derivative[1][φ][τ], 
    t -> t[τ], 
    r -> r[τ], θ -> θ[τ], φ -> \
φ[τ]};
  deq = Table[
    coords[[i]]''[τ] == Simplify[geodesic[[i]] /. op], {i, 1, 
     n}]; deq = 
   Join[deq, Table[coords[[i]]'[0] == ivs[[i]], {i, 1, n}], 
    Table[coords[[i]][0] == ics[[i]], {i, 1, n}]]; 
  soln = NDSolve[deq, coords, {τ, 0, maxτi}]; soln]
 uinvar = \[Minus]1; 
sphslnToCartsln[soln_] := 
 Block[{xs, ys, zs}, 
  xs = r[τ] Sin[θ[τ]] Cos[φ[τ]] /. 
    soln; ys = 
   r[τ] Sin[θ[τ]] Sin[φ[τ]] /. soln; 
  zs = r[τ] Cos[θ[τ]] /. soln; {xs, ys, zs}]
udotu[solni_, τval_] := 
 Block[{xα, uα}, 
  xα = 
   Table[coords[[i]][τ] /. solni, {i, 1, n}] // Flatten; 
  uα = D[xα, τ]; 
  xα = xα /. τ -> τval; 
  uα = uα /. τ -> τval; 
  uα.((metric /. 
       Table[coords[[i]] -> xα[[i]], {i, 1, n}]).uα)]
 coordlist[τin_] := 
 Table[ToString[coords[[i]]] <> 
   " = " <> {ToString[coords[[i]][τin] /. soln // First]}, {i, 1,
    n}]

soln = computeSoln[maxτ, ivs, ics];

xyzsoln = sphslnToCartsln[soln];
Join[{"Final Coordinates:"}, coordlist[maxτ]] // TableForm
Join[{{"", "", "", "u.u values"}}, 
  Table[{"τ=", ToString[i], "->", udotu[soln, i]}, {i, 0, 
    maxτ, maxτ/5}]] // TableForm
{Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[coords[[i]][τ] /. soln, {i, 1, n}]], {τ, 0, 
   maxτ}, AxesLabel -> {"τ", "Coordinate"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"t", "r", "θ", "φ"}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 30}], 
 Show[ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{xyzsoln[[1]], xyzsoln[[2]]} // Flatten], { τ, 0, 
    maxτ}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Gray], 
  Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 2]}]]}
```

[image: fig1]

To get the pictures on pp. 23-24, we need to change the settings

```
a=.9; maxτ = 200; ivs = {-0.15, 0, .002}; ics = {0, 10, π/2, 
  Pi/4}; M = 1; uinvar = 0;
```

and print options

```
{Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[coords[[i]][τ] /. soln, {i, 1, n}]], {τ, 0, 
   maxτ}, AxesLabel -> {"τ", "Coordinate"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"t", "r", "θ", "φ"}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 30}], 
 Show[ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{xyzsoln[[1]], xyzsoln[[2]]} // Flatten], { τ, 0, 
    maxτ}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Gray], 
  Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, M + Sqrt[M^2 - a^2]]}]]}
```

[image: fig2]

Consider the scattering of light rays in the Schwarzschild metric

```
a=0; max\[Tau] = 150; ivs = {-0.15, 0, .02}; ics = {0, 10, \[Pi]/4, 
  Pi/4}; M = 1;
Show[ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{xyzsoln[[1]], xyzsoln[[2]]} // Flatten], { \[Tau], 0, 
    max\[Tau]}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Gray, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 5}, {-7, 8}}], 
  Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, M + Sqrt[M^2 - a^2]]}]]}
```

[image: fig3]

Comment: This is great, thanks! Just one thing, if I wanted to do a similar thing but get the trajectory of a light ray in a Schwarzschild orbit rather than a massive particle (what the code in this document is doing) would it be correct just to edit the "univar" function and set it equal to 0 rather than -1? It has a statement about this at the bottom of page 3 (how they are considering massive particles) and at the bottom of page 6 about setting up the initial conditions.

Comment: If you want to get pictures on pages 23-24, then you need to put `uinvar = 0; a = 0.9` and change other parameters. See update to my answer.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, so basically you can fiddle around with the parameters and get whatever trajectory you would like. For instance by setting uinvar = 0; a = 0 you get a light trajectory in a Schwarzschild geometry too.

Comment: How could I fiddle the other parameters like maxt, ivs and ics (for Schwarzschild light orbit its obvious that Univar = 0 and a=0) to get a meaningful plot for the Schwarzschild light orbit curves (Not the Kerr as is done in the booklet)?

Comment: @user61882 See update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Alex but why is it the case that when I copy the code directly into a blank Mathematica document I get something different? For instances if I copy the first block and then the code for pages 22 it doesn't seem to replicate the images. Instead of getting the light trajectory I end up with something which looks like the original image for a particle orbit just with a fraction of the orbit plotted. Is it because I need to alter the parameters in the initial block instead?

Comment: Don't worry I have fixed the issue. Just want to know you know when you run the code and get table outputs for the tau values, how could I add an extra column to get each of the 4 coordinates at that particular tau value? Do you have to use the String command, if so what do you string it to in-order to the the coordinates listed.

Comment: Use code `Join[{{"", "", "", "u.u values", "t", "r", "\[Theta]", 
    "\[CurlyPhi]"}}, 
  Table[{"\[Tau]=", ToString[i], "->", udotu[soln, i], 
    coords[[1]][i] /. soln, coords[[2]][i] /. soln, 
    coords[[3]][i] /. soln, coords[[4]][i] /. soln}, {i, 0, max\[Tau],
     max\[Tau]/5}]] // TableForm`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much Alex.

Comment: @user61882 You're welcome!

Comment: Hi, another question just popped up to me, you know the variables defined as ivs, ics how are they related to our initial conditions, like do they represent the angle and radial distance needed to specify what curve we want?

Comment: The coordinates `ics` are used directly as the initial data, and the fourth component is added to the speed data `ivs`.

Comment: Ok, when you say the fourth component is added to the speed data what do you mean? Does the ivs only have 3 components since 1 of them is time and the other 3 are spatial? So each of the 3 spatial coordinates have a speed component?

Comment: I mean the line of code ` ivs = Join[{χ}, ivsi]; χslv = Solve[tmp == uinvar, χ]; 
  ivs[[1]] = Last[χ /. χslv];`. For discussion, see p. 4 of KerrOrbitGRProject with words "While it may seem incorrect to use an initial velocity of 1.1, ...".

Comment: The code is bit unclear to me. What is the role of the variable χ in the line "ivs = Join[{χ}, ivsi]" ? Kindly explain .... Soumen

Comment: @SoumenBasak Are the remaining lines of code clear?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Great answer, I found that the second half of your code is not the same as the result you posted in the answer after running on version 12.1.

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68 I have tested code on 12.0.0 and 12.1.1 for Windows 10. In the last picture we should use `AspectRatio -> Automatic`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Is there a problem in computing the contravariant form of the Kerr metric when a is not equal to 0? So how to get the contravariant form of Kerr?

Comment: @Stone It could be better to start a new topic with your problem explanation.